# how to get selected value in this plain select

Tags: reactjs

this is my code details, i want to get the selected value from the api to display in the textfield

```
<PlainSelect
              name="id"
              label="Tetapan"
              defaultObject={{
                value: form.id,
                label: form.id_text,
              }}
              value={form.id ? form.id : ""}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              api={{
                override: {
                  url: "kodstandardutama/kod/ref_tetapan_menu",

                  method: "get",
                },
```

Comment: Are you fetching the request in ```PlainSelect```?

Comment: yes ,im fetching the request in PlainSelect

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: okay i will try it..thank you

Comment: Glad that help.

Answer (score 0):

The value that `select` shows should be put here

```
const yourComponent = () => {
     const res = // your api fetching function


return (
    <PlainSelect>
        //other props 
        value={res.value}
    </PlainSelect>  
)
```